# cannot update default project visibility to private

Tags: sonarqube

We have configured Sonarqube 6.7.3 fresh setup (no history, no old data). I am trying to update the default project visibility to private using admin credentials as well as my account which is added to sonar-admin group but getting below error

```
Unknown url : /api/organizations/update_project_visibility
```

[image]

[image]

Any idea about this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've hit [SONAR-10569](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONAR-10569). It's fixed in 6.7.4 and 7.2.

Comment: Can you share expected release date for 6.7.4?

Comment: It is back in 7.1 build 11001

Comment: Thank you. I hope to get the Docker image soon since it is still 7.1 which is the latest.

Comment: No Docker image for 7.2 @AlexeyZimarev.

Comment: Update: The latest Docker image for the community edition is 7.7 so the setting is available again.

Answer (score 0):

Building on G. Ann's accepted answer I would like to highlight that you find this setting on the Project Administration page of your SonarQube instance `/admin/projects_management`

[image: sonarqube administration page]